# Using Ember.js for some views only with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have Rails app which I would like to implement Ember.js with.

I just want this to be used with some pages/views and not all of them.

I tried to do some but it seems javascript is being rendered afterwards (which is predicted) so when I render a partial view, it doesn't get rendered inside but rather just before body's closing tag.

Is there a good way to structure this or should I use the entire view to run with Ember.js?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Could be more specific on what you are trying to do and include relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `rootElement` when you create your Ember app to tell Ember where to embed the app.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: "#emberMain"
});
```